# Make PHP-FPM a drop-in replacement for PHP-CLI

Tags: php, linux

I have a minimalistic web server based on Centos 7 minimal, running PHP-FPM 7.1. I need to run some PHP-scripts from the command-line (CLI). I'm not the creator of those scripts and they can change over time.
The simple solution would be to install PHP-Cli on the server and be done with it but it seems a bit like a waste since I already have PHP-FPM (it would also be helpful to run PHP-FPM from the command-line to access some caches that are not shared between the two PHP-versions).

I know that I can execute files from the command-line using PHP-FPM but what I'm wondering is if it's possible to create a bash-script, or something, that would act as a drop-in replacement for how PHP-Cli is normally run from the command-line? So everything that would normally be run by PHP-Cli would be run by PHP-FPM without any special customization in the call.

In my example do I have a file, that has been given the execute permission, that starts with "#!/usr/bin/php" and the rest is PHP.
Would it be possible, for example, to create a script that calls PHP-FPM and save it as /usr/bin/php? Some problems would be to add all needed parameters automagically when calling PHP-FPM (SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_FILENAME, QUERY_STRING, DOCUMENT_ROOT,REQUEST_METHOD etc)

I hope that you see where I'm going with this and can see past any errors in my thought-process and answer the main question.

Here is some info about using PHP-FPM from the command-line: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/directly-connect-php-fpm/

Comment: Have you considered "webifying" these scripts?  You could add a couple of checks to ensure the request is from `localhost`, then just call with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or other.  It's slightly more overhead than just executing the script directly, but -- since I assume you're avoiding the `cgi-fcgi` route intentionally -- would eschew entirely the need for `php-cli`

Comment: I do not want to change the scripts since they can be updated later on.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research and testing did I give up trying to make it work with PHP-FPM and simply installed PHP CLI and used that with the script.

The problem I got stuck on was that you cannot set/pass $argv parameters to a php script when using PHP-FPM. You can only set get/post variables, so PHP scripts created to be run by PHP CLI, that uses parameters like that, cannot be run by PHP-FPM from the command line.
If you are creating the scripts yourself then you can build around it but if you did not, and do not want to modify them, you are stuck.